# Angular Directive is not being called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

The directive does not get called for some reason. The app is a rails app. I am using angular js on only one page. the ng-app is used on a div instead of body since the rest of the application uses rails.

The console does not give me any errors.

[image: Console]

```js
//app.coffee

angular.module('analytics', ['ngResource','ngRoute', 'highcharts-ng'])
  .config ($routeProvider, $logProvider) ->
   $logProvider.debugEnabled(true)


// Directive
                
angular.module('analytics', ['ngResource', 'highcharts-ng']).directive('addButton', () ->
 return {
  restrict : 'E'
  template : '<p> Hey directive here, </p>'
  replace: true
    }
 )

//main_ctrl.coffee

angular.module('analytics',['ngResource', 'highcharts-ng']).controller('MainCtrl',($scope, $http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) ->
 #Initial data to display in chart
 $http.get('http://localhost:3000/analytics/sales.json')
  .success((data) ->
   chartData = JSON.parse JSON.stringify(data)
   $scope.chartConfig =
    options:
     chart:
      type: 'line'
    series:[
     {
     data: chartData.sales
     }
    ]
    xAxis:
     categories: chartData.months
     title:
      text: 'Months'
  )
  .error((data) ->
  )
  $scope.branch = [];
  $scope.company = [];
  $scope.item = [];
  $scope.filters = ->

   params = 
    branch_filter: JSON.stringify $scope.branch
    company_filter: JSON.stringify $scope.company
    item:  JSON.stringify $scope.item
   
   $http.get('http://localhost:3000/analytics/sales.json',{params: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(params)})
    .success((data) ->
     chartData = JSON.parse JSON.stringify(data)
     console.log chartData.months
     $scope.chartConfig =
      options:
       chart:
        type: 'line'
      series:[
       {
       data: chartData.sales
       }
      ]
      xAxis:
       categories: chartData.months
       title:
        text: 'Months'
    )
    .error((data) ->
    )
   
  
 
 )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

.container#graph-container[ng-app="analytics" ng-controller="MainCtrl"]
  .row
    highchart#chart1 config="chartConfig"
 .row
    .col-md-2.top-padding.bottom-padding
      select.form-control#sales_branch_filter.chosen-select ng-model="branch" ng-change="filters()" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Branch Filter"
       - Branch.alphabetical.each do |branch|
        option value="#{branch.id}" #{branch.name}
    .col-md-2.top-padding.bottom-padding
      select.form-control#sales_item_filter.chosen-select ng-model="item" ng-change="filters()" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Item Filter"
       - Item.alphabetical.each do |item|
        option value="#{item.id}" #{item.name}
    .col-md-2.top-padding.bottom-padding
      select.form-control#sales_company_filter.chosen-select ng-model="company" ng-change="filters()" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Company Filter"
       - Company.alphabetical.each do |company|
        option value="#{company.id}" #{company.name}         
 .row
      add-button
      br
      button.btn.btn-primary#add ng-click="add()" Add
      br
    .col-md-12.sales-container
     = render partial: 'sales_table'
```

Comment: I am trying to run snippet but I your code running failed. can you import codes to plnkr.co and after I can help you

Comment: The code snippet will fail. Because it's part of a rails application and Stackoverflow's code snippet does not support 'slim' and 'coffeescript'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the add_button.coffee file. Because that is getting loaded before the app.coffee file and that is why your controllers are working. That is how it is with rails. Also remove the dependencies from the controller file and directive file. It is overwriting the module already defined.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new module each time.

angular.module(moduleName, []) creates a new module. You should call it only once and then use angular.module(moduleName) to get this module. Or even better, store a module into a variable

```
var analytics = angular.module('analytics', ['ngResource','ngRoute', 'highcharts-ng']);
analytics.config(.....)
analytics.directive(.....)
// .....
```

Comment: The two angular.module are from two different files. I have seperate files for config, controllers, services and directives

Answer (score 0):

> Beware that using `angular.module('myModule', [])` will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing module.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

You are calling it with two parameters all the time so you are overwriting the module every time you want to reference it.

So try calling `angular.module('analytics', ['ngResource','ngRoute', 'highcharts-ng'])` once at the beginning and reference it further just as `angular.module('analytics')` should solve your problem.

Comment: The two angular.module are from two different files. I have seperate files for config, controllers, services and directives

Comment: No. There are 2 of these functions provided by the AngularJS framework.
[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) Search for 
'Creation versus Retrieval

Comment: Now I removed it from other files except for the configuration file. The directive still does not work. The controller works though.

Comment: Now I put the directive's, the controller's and the config's code in one file and did as you suggested and the directives work. Now how do I put them in different files and get them to work?

Comment: Just use `angular.module('myModule')` to get the module. But make sure the file with the module creation is included at first